# Terraform returns 500 on MongoDB Atlas cluster creation

Tags: mongodb, terraform

Terraform gives back an error when I create a cluster for MongoDB Atlas. I have a premium Mongo account and creation of other resources like mongodb_container, database_user, atlas_project etc worked with TF. But for cluster creation, I get the error posted below.

```
Error: error creating MongoDB Cluster: POST https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/606391c736b8af0a227cb763/clusters: 500 (request "UNEXPECTED_ERROR") Unexpected error.
    
  on atlas-infra.tf line 20, in resource "mongodbatlas_cluster" "test-cluster":
  20: resource "mongodbatlas_cluster" "test-cluster" {
```

Here my script for cluster resource:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_cluster" "test-cluster" {
  project_id   = mongodbatlas_project.test_db.id
  name         = "test-cluster"
  cluster_type = "REPLICASET"
  replication_specs {
    num_shards = 1
    regions_config {
      region_name     = var.atlas_region
      electable_nodes = 1
      priority        = 7
      read_only_nodes = 0
    }
  }
  provider_backup_enabled      = true
  auto_scaling_disk_gb_enabled = true
  mongo_db_major_version       = "4.2"

  //Provider Settings "block"
  provider_name               = "GCP"
  disk_size_gb                = 10
  provider_instance_size_name = "M10"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm answering my question. The value I was passing for region is "US_EAST_1", as referenced in this example [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mongodb/mongodbatlas/latest/docs/resources/cluster). But the actual values are [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/google-gcp/)